# How to change automatic variable generation in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

With PhpStorm, if you type `function foo(MyClass $`, it will propose `myClass` as the variable name.

But since I added a WordPress project (I accepted default settings for WordPress as proposed), it propose `my_class` instead.

I really would like to bring back the camel case naming by default, but I don't find where it is configured.

Is there an option for this? Or maybe a configuration file to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), go to **Editor** >  **Code Style** > **PHP**, then click the **Other** tab. At the bottom of the screen, you should see the *Variable Naming Style* section. Select **camelCase**.

[image]